# passport google auth20 not sending to google log in screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Hello here I have a server, I am trying to send the user to google auth screen when the path /auth/google is called. But instead I get my 404 screen. I am routing using both express routers and some react routes on the frontend.

Server:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const path = require("path");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(session({
    secret: "temp",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bindrake", {useNewUrlParser: true});


//Models
const User = require("./models/user");
const Key = require("./models/key");

//ROUTES
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoutes");

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/bindrake",
    userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use("/api", userRoute);

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

if (true){
    app.use(express.static("./public/build"));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "build", "index.html"));
    })
}


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Is there any idea why, please let me know if you need to see more of the code. Maybe I am doing something wrong while routing it?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh okey, it just worked. I just needed to wait after creating the credentials.